# What happens when using higher version tf serving to serve a model from lower version tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have trained and exported a model with tensorflow 1.12.

Then I tested tf-serving 2.1.0、1.15.0、1.12.0 separately to serve the `saved_model`.

Then I got right results with tf-serving 1.12.0

the results of tf-serving 2.1.0 and 1.15.0 are the same but wrong.

---

I made another test, use tf-serving 2.1.0 and 1.15.0 separately to serve a model trained by tensorflow 1.15. This time the two results are the same right. It seems tf-serving 2.1.0 and 1.15.0 could make the same results.

---

Isn't tf serving backward compatible?

I haven't got any warning or error throughout these experiments.